# Programmatically add an Icon in Android LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout

```
                for (int i = 0; i < tel.size(); i++) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.telefones, null);
                TextView tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.telefone);
                tv.setText(tel.get(i).getNumero());
                l1.addView(vi);

                View divider = new View(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);

                divider.setLayoutParams(lp);
                if((i+1)<tel.size()){
                    divider.setBackgroundColor(0x66728c93);
                }else{

                    divider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                l1.addView(divider);


            }
```

The above code gives me the following result:

[image]

Now, What I'm trying to do is add a message icon aligned to the right of the phone number like so:

[image]

How can I programmatically put that icon in my layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is quite simple using `android:drawableRight || top || left || bottom`.

Example:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_adr"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/action_place"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_image"/>
```

See [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) docs form more info

And [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) you can find the image icons freely to download.

Comment: but you wont be able to give padding

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a nested layout. Perhaps an horizontally aligned LinearLayout that hosts your TextView (width=0dp and weight = 1) and the icon (width=wrap_content).

Answer (score 1):

The method

`TextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`

is what you need to add icon programmatically.
Documentation [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))